# Why is the 'OnLeave' event of my textbox not available and how can I work around this?

Tags: c#, asp.net, textbox

I am building a c# asp.net Web form which contains a textbox available for user input. I want the user to be forced to enter something in this textbox i.e. he may not leave the textbox blank. So I need the focus to be on this textbox until the user has input text.

In the .aspx I have the following code:

```
<td>
    Account <asp:TextBox ID="tbAccount" runat="server" OnTextChanged="tbAccount_TextChanged" AutoPostBack="true"></asp:TextBox>
</td>
```

And my c# code to fire when the text in the textbox is changed is:

```
protected void tbAccount_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            if (tbAccount.Text == "")
            {
                lblMessage.Text = "YOU CAN'T LEAVE THE ACCOUNT FIELD BLANK";
                tbAccount.Focus();
            }
            else
            {
                lblMessage.Text = "ACCOUNT ENTERED CORRECTLY";
            }
        }
```

My problem is that the text must be changed for this class to be called. So if the user tabs on to the textbox and leaves the textbox without entering anything, then the code does not get called. What I really want is the "OnLeave" event for the textbox but for some reason this option is not available???

If anyone can help with a way around this it would be greatly appreciated.

Johnathan.

Comment: OnBlur which is what the event that fires when a control loses focus , does not make sense as a server side event. You don't need to hack it like this, just use a `RequiredFieldValidator` and set SetFocusOnError to true.

Comment: OnBlur is not an available option either. The only ones available are: OnDataBinding, OnDisposed, OnInit, OnLoad, OnPreRender, OnUnload and OnTextChanged.

Comment: Ben, this would work but I need the error message to appear as soon as the user leaves the textbox rather than at a later stage (e.g. when a button is pushed).